# difference between android:actionMenuTextColor and actionMenuTextColor

Tags: android

I am using my application theme as in the given my actionMenuTextColor is not working.

```
 <style name="MyCustomTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">        // My Custom theme for Application which is not working            
                    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>                            // For No title bar                    
                    <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>                // For No Action bar
                    <item name="android:actionMenuTextColor">@color/white</item>  
                </style>
```

In this code if I replace

```
 <item name="android:actionMenuTextColor">@color/white</item>  by
      <item name="actionMenuTextColor">@color/white</item>
```

then it starts working ,So what is the difference between using any item with android:tagName or simply tagName ?

Comment: The code in "if I replace" part is the same. Please update it, as right now I do not understand your question.

Comment: I have edited my code if i replace "android:actionMenuTextColor" by "actionMenuTextColor" it works

Answer (score 5):

`android:actionMenuTextColor` is for high API levels, and `actionMenuTextColor` is for support library ( lower API levels )

You should have both if using support library.

Comment: i have tried "android:actionMenuTextColor" with API level 21 , it does not work.

Comment: @VaibhavJain You have to use both `actionMenuTextColor` and `android:actionMenuTextColor`, if you want to support API 21 and above.